# error during training the chatbot in chatterbot

Tags: chatterbot

this are my codes

from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import spacy

nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

bot = ChatBot("chatbot", read_only=False, logic_adapters=["chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"])

list=[
"hi",
"hi there",
"what your name",
"chatbot",
"how old",
"age less!"
]

list_trainer=ListTrainer(bot)

list_trainer.train(list)

but this error occur

PS C:\Users\Timoth\Desktop\chatbot>  & 'C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe' 'c:\Users\Timoth.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2023.18.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '49893' '--' 'c:\Users\Timoth\Desktop\chatbot\index.py'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Timoth\Desktop\chatbot\index.py", line 5, in 
bot = ChatBot("chatbot", read_only=False, logic_adapters=["chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"])
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0a7-py3.11.egg\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in **init**
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0a7-py3.11.egg\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0a7-py3.11.egg\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in **init**
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0a7-py3.11.egg\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 22, in **init**
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chatterbot-1.1.0a7-py3.11.egg\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 26, in **init**
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy_*init*_.py", line 51, in load
return util.load_model(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Timoth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 471, in load_model
from a shortcut, which is obsolete as of spaCy v3.0. To load the model, use its full name instead:

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

For more details on the available models, see the models directory: https://spacy.io/models and if you want to create a blank model, use spacy.blank: nlp = spacy.blank("en")

I exoected the bot to be trained